# Как сравнивать элементы массивов, если у них разная длина?

Tags: java

У меня есть функция в которую я подаю два массива, и пытаюсь выеtсти число одинаковых
элементов в обоих массивах, но вот беда, эти массивы имеют разную длину, как можно сделать что
бы программа не выдавала ошибку **Index 3 out of bounds for length 3**

```
        int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] arr2 = {1, 2, 2, 2};

        System.out.print(tablica01.licznosc(arr1, arr2));
```

```
    public int licznosc (int[] talica01, int[] talica02) {
        int counter = 0;
        Arrays.sort(talica01);
        Arrays.sort(talica02);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(talica01.length, talica02.length); i++) {
            if (talica01[i] == talica02[i])
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: `i < Math.max(talica01.length, talica02.length)` тут точно `max` а не `min` ?

Comment: Но если будет ```min``` то тогда у меня не проверятся остальные элементы в массиве длина которого больше

Comment: Вот теперь подумайте над алгоритмом - как вы хотите список из 2 и из 22 элементов, что должно получиться

Comment: Не совсем понимаю о чем Вы

Comment: Ожидаемое поведение какое, что вы хотите получить в результате, и по какому алгоритму? )

Comment: Ну допусти у меня два массива ```{1, 2, 3}``` i ```{1, 2, 2, 3}``` в результате должно быть 3, а программа покажет 2

Comment: Распишите подробнее в вопросе, какова первоначальная задача. Приведите примеры входных данных. Сейчас неясно, что вы ожидаете и почему, например, 3, а не 4 или 2.

Comment: Ну для начала я сортирую массивы, и дальше по очереди если arr1[0] == arr2[0](и так в цикле каждый эдлементы с каждым должен быть проверен) то counter я увеличиваю на 1.

Comment: Какие результаты ожидаете для `{1, 1}` и `{1}`? `{1}` и `{1, 1}`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов для обов случаев ожидаю ответ: 1

Comment: Так а что вы считаете то в итоге? Количество совпадающих пар?

Comment: @Kromster да, это и считаю

Comment: Ладно, вижу вместо помощи с алгоритмом мне на вопрос ставят только минусы, спасибо, можете вообще закрыть его

Comment: Тогда напишите это в вопросе и вообще его переформулируйте. Потому как в текущем виде, ваш вопрос "не о том".

Comment: @Kromster это ваши комментарии "не о том".

Comment: Не обижайтесь, я вас пытаюсь вывести на правильную нить рассуждений. Сначала нужно задачу поставить, потом алгоритм составить, а потом уже в коде ошибки исправлять ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Какие результаты ожидаете для `{1, 1}` и `{1}`? `{1}` и `{1, 1}`?

> @МихаилМуругов для обов случаев ожидаю ответ: 1

Тогда предлагаю следующее решение:

```java
    public int licznosc (int[] talica01, int[] talica02) {
        // Приводим оба массива к Set (коллекция уникальных элементов)
        Set<Integer> lhs = Arrays.stream(talica01).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Set<Integer> rhs = Arrays.stream(talica02).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

        // Оставляем в lhs только те элементы, что есть и в rhs
        lhs.retainAll(rhs);

        return lhs.size();
    }
```